# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list' - A column was not found

Tags: php, laravel

Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $guard = 'admin';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'type',
        'phone',
        'email',
        'password',
        'image',
        'status',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

Controller

```
public function updateCurrentPassword(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->isMethod('post')){
            $data = $request->all();
            //Check if current password is correct
            if(Hash::check($data['current_password'], Auth::guard('admin')->user()->password)){
                // Check if new and confirm password is matching
                if($data['new_password'] == $data['confirm_password']){
                    Admin::where('id', Auth::guard('admin')->user()->id)->update(['password' == bcrypt($data['new_password'])]);
                    Session::flash('success_message', 'Password has been updated successfully!');
                }else{
                    Session::flash('error_message', 'New password and confirm password different!');
                }
            }else{
                Session::flash('error_message', 'Your current password is incorrect!');
            }
            return redirect()->back();
        }
    }
```

Migration file

```
class CreateAdminsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('admins', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('type');
            $table->string('phone');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('image');
            $table->integer('status');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('admins');
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following error when i submit the form. Couldn't figure out what is happening. I just don't understand the error. Is it something wrong with timestamp?

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list' (SQL: update `admins` set `0` = 0, `admins`.`updated_at` = 2021-09-06 16:49:47 where `id` = 1)
> http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/update-current-password

Comment: `['password' == bcrypt($data['new_password'])]` should be `['password' => bcrypt($data['new_password'])]`

Comment: Please extract a [mcve] and do a bit of research on the error you got. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-updates

I see the `update` method expects an array of column and value pairs representing the columns that should be updated.

So, your code:
`update(['password' == bcrypt($data['new_password'])]);`

should change to:
`update(['password' => bcrypt($data['new_password'])]);`

Comment: Thank you. I never noticed it >.<